# QueryDSL Left Join with additional conditions in ON

Tags: java, left-join, querydsl

Is it possible to do the following query in QueryDSL?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parts_table p LEFT JOIN inventory_balance_table i ON 
    (p.part_no = i.part_no 
     AND i.month = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
     AND i.year = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE));
```

Inventory balance stores inventory data for every part number/month/year; I need the only the data for the current year and month.

I've gotten the basic left join down:

```
QPartsTable qParts = QPartsTable.partsTable;
QInventoryBalance qBalance = QInventoryBalance.inventoryBalance;

JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(em);
q.from(qParts).leftJoin(qParts.inventoryBalance, qBalance);
q.where(...);
List<Part> list = q.list(qParts);
```

which makes the correct sql, but only joining on the part number.

The resulting parts are checked for stock availability (among other things). The left join is necessary, because I still need parts that don't have an inventory entry yet (new parts for instance). Left join will get those without a matching inventory balance, but adding `month = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)` and so on to where clause of the query removes the rows without an inventory balance (because they don't have year/month data).

For the same reason `@Where` and `@Filter` would remove those parts from the resulting parts list and are not applicable. Sadly `@Filter` and `@Where` are the only other results I'm getting with a search in Google and here on SO. (Oddly the Filter doesn't even affect the query even if filters are enabled in the session...)

The simplest solution would be my original question: How to turn the above SQL into QueryDSL? In general, is it possible to add more and/or custom conditions to the ON clause of the left join? What are the alternative solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update** - A follow-up question and an observation: (Perhaps this should be a new question entirely?)

After looking through the docs, it seems the older blogs demonstrating querydsl had the `on()` function for `leftJoin`'s. Why is this no longer the case?

`SQLQuery` (or `HibernateSQLQuery` or some other variety) has the on() function, but leftJoin() accepts `RelationalPath<T>`, not an `EntityPath<T>` as `JPAQuery` does. It seems impossible to cast QClasses to a `RelationalPath`, so that's probably not the way to go...

---

**Update 2** - We're using 2.9.0. Using `on()` gives an error, like it doesn't exist...

Comment: That's because it doesn't exist in `2.9.0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to use `on()` in QueryDSL, including the latest version. `JPAQuery` also supports `on()` predicate.

So this can be achieved,

```
QPartsTable qParts = QPartsTable.partsTable;
QInventoryBalance qBalance = QInventoryBalance.inventoryBalance;

JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(em);
q.from(qParts).leftJoin(qParts.inventoryBalance, qBalance).on(qBalance.month.eq(yourMonth).and(qBalance.year.eq(yourYear))).list(qParts);
```

`JPAQuery` implements `JPQLCommonQuery` interface, so as others it has all necessary methods.

Here are docs from [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.2/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e1103) latest version with left join using `on()` example.

**Update:**

`on()` has been introduced since QueryDsl 3.0.0 version. So for versions below 3.0.0 it is not available.

I'd suggest to upgrade your version at least to 3.0.0, as the API is quite stronger comparing to old versions. Even more, I'd strongly advice to upgrade to the latest stable version (3.6.2), there shouldn't be any problems as new API supports everything as before, with additional features.

**Update 2:**
As @Cezille07 mentioned in the comment, there is a `with()` alternative for `on()`, in older versions. As we see from the [issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/299) , `with()` has been replaced with `on()` later on.

So for older versions `with()` does the trick. Here is a usefull [link](http://blog.mysema.com/2013/03/querydsl-30-in-nutshell.html) with more details.

Comment: We're using querydsl 2.9.0. It's there in that link, but when I use `on(...)` it has an error "The method on(BooleanExpression) is undefined for the type JPAQuery". The on doesn't even appear in the auto-complete list of functions for JPAQuery.

Comment: Now we know the problem :) 2.9.0 does not support ```on``` expression, you should upgrade at least one version to 3.0.0. Please take a look on my edited answer, I included this information there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info! After some digging, for the old version there is the function `with` that does what `on` does. [link](http://blog.mysema.com/2013/03/querydsl-30-in-nutshell.html) Could you please add that bit and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Very usefull info! Thanks, I have added that to my answer for future visitors. Great finding, didnt know about that.