# "MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" when joining three depth table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously
>   fetch multiple bags: [Order.items, OrderItem.options];

Above is an exception i faced when i join three tables like below.

OrderItemOption.java

```
@Entity
public class OrderItemOption {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "item_option_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
  private Long itemId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "item_id",
      referencedColumnName = "item_id",
      insertable = false,
      updatable = false
  )
  private OrderItem orderItem;
}
```

OrderItem.java

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
  private Long orderId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "order_id",
      referencedColumnName = "order_id",
      insertable = false,
      updatable = false,
      nullable = false
  )
  private Order order;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "orderItem")
  @OrderBy("item_option_id ASC")
  private List<OrderItemOption> options;
}
```

Order.java

```
@Entity
public class Order {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
  @OrderBy("item_id ASC")
  private List<OrderItem> items;
}
```

And here's my QueryDSL code to join them at one time.

```
final QOrder order = QOrder.order;
final QOrderItem item = QOrderItem.orderItem;
final QOrderItemOption option = QOrderItemOption.orderItemOption;

from(order)
.leftJoin(order.items, item).fetchJoin()
.leftJoin(item.options, option).fetchJoin()
.where(
    order.id.eq(orderId)
        .and(item.id.in(itemIds))
        .and(option.id.in(optionIds))
)
.fetchOne())
```

What i'm trying to do is to get Order object which contains filtered relationship, so that i can access filtered children via order object. 
and the type of relationship should be a List, not a Set.

for example, order.getItems().get(0).getOptions.get(0)

How can i achieve that goal?

Answer (score 10):

To avoid above exception there are two possibilities:

1. Change `List` to `Set`
   or
2. Use `List` but do not fetch two bags. This means don't use `fetchJoin()` on both collections.

Filtering:

Using where conditions collections will be not filtered.  Collections will contain all associated objects. Joining in JPA is for creating conditions on root object - Order. It is not the same as in SQL.

It is possible to filter associated collections using JPA 2.1 `JOIN ON` feature. This allows additional conditions in `ON` clause

see for example [QueryDSL Left Join with additional conditions in ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849713/querydsl-left-join-with-additional-conditions-in-on)

Comment: About changing List to Set to fetch multiple collections, be aware of the performance issue : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088649/how-to-use-multiple-join-fetch-in-one-jpql-query

Answer (score 4):

If you really can not use Set instead of List:

**Parent.class**

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "parent",
    orphanRemoval = true,
    cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }
)
@OrderColumn(name = "position")
private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Child.class**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Parent parent;
```

And create a column in the Child's table named e.g "position"

```
ALTER TABLE child ADD COLUMN position integer NOT NULL default 0
```

And if you can not use other column in table, them you need to query the lists in sequence. Or use the id of the child and a custom getter.

```
@OrderColumn(name = "id_child", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public List<Child> getChilds() {
    childs.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    return childs;
}
```